# ms-access queries

Tags: ms-access

I never really did ms access queries, but today I need one. I have 2 tables, models and orders. From first table one 2 fields are of interest here: number and color, from second only number which can only be equal to values of number from table "models" . What I need is to select most frequent color. In mysql that would be something like

```
    SELECT models.color, orders.number  FROM  models
    INNER JOIN orders ON (orders.number =models.number) 
    group by color
    order by count(color) desc limit 1
```

But in ms-access that doesn't seem to work
How do you write query to do same thing in ms-access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 models.color, COUNT(orders.number)  FROM  models
INNER JOIN orders ON (orders.number=models.number) 
GROUP BY models.color
ORDER BY 2 desc
```

Comment: This will return more than one row when there are matching counts. Top n is not exactly the same as Limit n

Comment: Works in my case though so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: You can use the select top 1 statement, but keep in mind that TOP is the last thing in access sql order of operations, so beware of query slowdowns.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to get rid of limit and use Top 1 instead:

```
SELECT Top 1 models.color  FROM  models
INNER JOIN orders ON (orders.number =models.number) 
group by color
order by count(color) Desc
```

However, there is a caveat for Top *n*, in MS Access, Top *n* will return matches, so if several items have the same count, all will be returned. If this does not suit, you can work around this by ordering by a unique id as well:

```
order by count(color) desc, OrderID
```

Note also that number is a reserved word.

Comment: That gives "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression "number" as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: That worked but returned something weird. First row was White which had 1 hit, and then Red which had 4 hits

Comment: The thing is, shouldn't it had returned only one row since other don't have same count?